# Error on LU decomposition

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I had a homework about writing LU decomposition with editor at MATLAB and proceed a bit. Now I got and error with my code. Which says

> Undefined function or variable 'B'.
>
> Error in LuA (line 4)
> m=size(B);

What should i do?

The code is :

```
function F= LuA( A )
input B;
input b;
m=size(B,1);
n=length(b);
A(1:n,1:n) = B(1,n:1,n);
A(:,n+1)=b;
F=A;
for i=1:n;
    %change diagonal elements to 1
    F(i,i+1:n+1)=A(i,i+1:n+1)/A(i,i);
    %change under of diagonal elements to 0
    for j=i+1:N;
        F(j,i+1:n+1)=A(j,i+1:n+1)-(A(j,i)*A(i,i+1:n+1));
    end
end
```

Comment: Is your homework to write the program? cause there are packages you can download

Comment: Yes it is, but I want to do it by myself and just looking for a bit hint.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about what you are trying to accomplish?  The LU decomposition does not require anything but the matrix `A`, so what are `B` and `b` supposed to represent? If I had to guess from your code, I would say that `A` is actually just composed of `B` and `b`.  In that case, your function should be `function F = LuA(B,b)` unless you are wanting to prompt the user for `B` and `b`.

Comment: @nispio They are written on the notes at class for showing a way but they are not necessary. I am trying to accomplish LU decomposition of a matrix then taking determinant of it withohut using ready commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than

```
input B;
input b;
```

you need to write something like

```
B = input('Enter B');
b = input('Enter b');
```

Cf. the [documentation for input](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/input.html).